# Using MQTT behind proxy using PAHO c / cpp

Tags: c++, sockets, mqtt, paho, mqtt-vernemq

So I have my paho client behind a ccproxy server with sock enabled.

The problem is in paho python lib there is a method exposed for setting proxy

`client.proxy_set(proxy_type=socks.HTTP, proxy_addr="192.168.1.7", proxy_port=808)`

Can someone guide me on the proxy setup for the same on cpp couldn't find much documentation in the docs or the community.

Comment: Can you clarify the first line. Do you mean you have access to a Socks Proxy server or a HTTP Proxy?

Comment: I have both socks & http proxy

Answer (score 0):

Paho Client for C++ does not seem to support proxies yet, see also this [issue](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.cpp/issues/265)

Comment: Even C is not supporting I believe, in the above link the second comment is mine. reaching out to community if anyone has implemented it.

Comment: Paho Client for C++ seems to be a wrapper around the Paho Client for C.
That one has support for HTTP Proxies, see https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c/blob/b3da4d6456550f3e48cf131e4f8017e964ad33fa/src/MQTTProtocolOut.c#L162

So using the http_proxy environment variable should trigger this. Howevery, this is still no support for SOCKS.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running the code on Linux.

Have you tried running the compiled application with the [socksify](https://linux.die.net/man/1/socksify) command?

This inserts a shim into the library that handles socket creation and wraps them in a connection to the Socks proxy (It looks like it may support HTTP Connect based proxying as well).

Comment: I'm on windows I did use proxifier to scoksify and it works but I need something built within my app

Comment: I've not played with pre-loading libraries on Windows but you should be able to do some tricks that sockify is doing at runtime with linking to get the same effect baked into the app.